# Host flutter web on apache server process?

Tags: flutter, apache, web, host

I want to host flutter web application on apache server, using command line.

Comment: Hi, pleased read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

### To host a Flutter web application on an Apache server ## using command line, you need to follow these steps:

1. Build the Flutter web application by running the following command in the terminal:

   ```
     > flutter build web
   ```
2. This command will create a "build" directory in the root of your project.
   Copy the contents of the "build" directory to the "public_html" directory of your Apache server. You can use the following command to do this:

> cp -R build/* /path/to/public_html/

3. Replace "/path/to/public_html/" with the actual path to the "public_html" directory of your Apache server.
   Configure Apache to serve the Flutter web application. Create a new file named ".htaccess" in the "public_html" directory and add the following code:

> RewriteEngine on  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]

4. This code will redirect all requests to the "index.html" file, which is the entry point of the Flutter web application. Restart the Apache server to apply the changes.

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

This command will restart the Apache server on Linux systems. If you are using a different operating system, the command to restart the Apache server may be different.

Your Flutter web application should now be accessible through your Apache server. You can access it by navigating to the URL of your Apache server in a web browser.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To deploy a Flutter web app on an Apache server, you will need to follow these steps:

1. Build the Flutter web app for production using the command 
    `flutter build web`.
2. Configure the Apache server to serve the app by adding the appropriate **VirtualHost** and **Directory directives** to the *Apache configuration files*.
3. Copy the built files to the webroot directory of your Apache server using the command 
    `sudo cp -r build/web/* /var/www/html/`.
4. Sometimes `/var/www/html/` destination is changed to `/var/www/folder_name` hosted folder
5. Restart the Apache server using the command 
    `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.
6. Test the app to make sure it works as expected.